# Find dynamic id attribute jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need help to find dynamic element using jQuery

```
<button id="awe1" data-href="http://awesome1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RemConfirm" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</button>

<button id="awe2" data-href="http://awesome2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RemConfirm" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</button>
```

If above button clicked it will show a modal, you can see button have dynamic 'data-href', I need to get this value and apply to modal button as confirm remove. I'm using bootstrap modal and this is my modal.

```
<div id="RemConfirm" class="modal modal-scroll fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You are about to remove this item ?.</p>
    <p class="debug-url"></p> <!-- debug data-href -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn shadow default">Close</button>
    <a class="btn remove-confirm">Remove</a>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#RemConfirm').on('show.modalmanager', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.remove-confirm').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.remove-confirm').attr('href') + '</strong>');
});
```

Comment: This question isn't clear enough. Could you explain it in a better way? It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: If I click a button it will show bootstrap modal, i need to get value of 'data-href' from that button and apply this value to modal button.

Answer (score 0):

I completed it in this fiddle, but your question isn't clear. I'm not sure what half of your jQuery does re: `$(e.relatedTarget)` and `show.modalmanager` as it's not defined.

The example below does it basically with the HTML available:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.remove-confirm').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).data('href') + '</strong>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="awe1" data-href="http://awesome1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RemConfirm" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</button>

<button id="awe2" data-href="http://awesome2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RemConfirm" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</button>

<div id="RemConfirm" class="modal modal-scroll fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You are about to remove this item ?.</p>
    <p class="debug-url"></p> <!-- debug data-href -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn shadow default">Close</button>
    <a class="btn remove-confirm">Remove</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to accomplish this with call my modal inside jQuery

my button:

```
<a href="http://awesome1" data-confirm="You are about to remove this item ?" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</a>

<a href="http://awesome2" data-confirm="You are about to remove this item ?" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</a>
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
      $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal modal-scroll fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button><h4 class="modal-title">Please Confirm</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn shadow default">Close</button><a type="button" class="btn shadow red-sunglo" id="dataConfirmTrue">Remove</a></div></div>');
    } 
    $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
    $('#dataConfirmTrue').attr('href', href);
    $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
    return false;
  });
});
```

thanks